# No puedo hacer el deploy en render de esta app MERN?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

https://github.com/Matricc89/mern-app-proyect

No puedo lograr pushear la app en render, es un proyecto que saque de youtube me gusto poder interpretarlo y hacerlo pero a la hora de hacer el deploy, el que lo hizo uso heroku, y ahora heroku  no esta disponible de forma gratuita, quiza alguien pueda darme una mano... Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Pues no queda claro el **por qué** no puedes lograr pushear tu app a render. Tendrías que proporcionar más información para poder ayudarte.